# Binary output-Bit manipulation with LC-3

Tags: assembly, lc3

First crack at assembly. So I'm messing around with an LC-3 sim. Implemented a simple `OR` instruction(not as a routine) and a few other things. Anyway, I know you can `.FILL` variables directly with binary numbers(`var .Fill b1110101`) but I'm wondering how to output contents of regs(or addresses) as binary. I used a dummy variable to store the int to make sure my bit operations were correct by viewing it directly in the simulator. Not exactly ideal.

Not sure you need any of that backround info but here's the (probably silly) question;

**How do you output binary data in LC-3 or at least view the reg contents in hex or binary?**

Comment: You write a function that converts it to text and outputs each bit using the appropriate `OUT` `TRAP`.  You can use a loop that tests the most significant bit using `BRn` and outputs `'0'` or `'1'` as appropriate, then adds the number to itself (shifts it left for the next bit).

Comment: Is [this previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12380400/how-would-you-go-about-converting-a-stored-hex-value-to-its-binary-equivalent-u) relevant?

Comment: Or [this](https://www.daniweb.com/programming/software-development/threads/499805/how-to-write-a-program-that-converts-hex-to-binary-lc3)? Simple google of the question's last line.